# What is the difference between MultiCore and MultiProcessor?

Tags: multi-core, multi-processor

What is the difference between MultiCore and MultiProcessor please?

Comment: See some of these comments on the recently asked question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257054/whats-the-difference-between-parallel-and-multicore-programming

Comment: Probably for superuser.com, but - multicore means multiple CPU cores on a single processor. Multiprocessor typically refers to systems that have multiple physical processors, like a server that runs two Intel processors on the same motherboard.

Answer (score 5):

One computer can have multiple processors.

One Processor can have multiple cores.